# Can I convert a Google Drive spreadsheet to Excel format from my phone?

Tags: google-drive

My work has blocked access to Google Docs. I need to print off something which is on there.

At my laptop at home, I normally just export a google document to excel format but on the app version, it allows me to "send" it to an email address but it seems to send it only in PDF format.

Is there a way I can export it into excel spreadsheet from the android app and send it to my work email.

Comment: Doesn't appear to be, no. It doesn't even look like going to  drive.google.com in the browser would be viable.

Comment: @AlEverett - i found a way but yeah it's pretty convoluted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems the only way to do it was to open up the document through the browser, selecting desktop mode.

Then "View spreadsheet mode" right at the bottom. 
Then it'll load it up like it would if you loaded it from a computer. Then you can select File -> Email as Attachment.

Bit of a crappy process...